# Proper noun capitalization in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Let me set the stage. I am working with a MySQL to input customer company names, for example "My Company" using PHP/PDO. In PHP, I am aware of the `ucwords(), ucfirst, strtoupper(), and strtolower()` functions. Are there any good practices as to how to handle the capitalization; meaning that I need to know if I should store them as Proper Noun format, all lowercase, all UPPERCASE, or would that depend on need. Currently, I am thinking either all UPPERCASE letters would be best.  First letter capitalization is a hassle to convert when I need to display to the user, query, or update the field especially when other users don't have the best capitalization skills. Luckily at this point, hyphenated names are not an issue. How have you handled these issues in the past?

Comment: You need better examples including the most preposterous edge cases you can dig up. Is "A Company" and "Example of Company" the form you want them in, as it's traditional to not capitalize words like "of", "a" or "the" in proper titles *if* they're not the first word.

Comment: better store all in lowercases.. my prefrence

Comment: First of all - go read up on the difference between how data is _stored_, and how it is _compared_ - __Collations__ would be the keyword here.

Comment: Maybe you have already answered my question. It looks like it is based on application need and not what is inherently grammatically correct. First Word is best for UI but all UPPERCASE is easier to work with when the user inputs information. EDIT: CBroe I am looking it up now.

Comment: Your users will input company names? Do I understand you correctly? If you want to have some standardization across database then I would agree with going uppercase.

Comment: It also depends on what you're going to do with it. If you will want to output it in a "correctly" capitalized way at some point, it's a tricky thing to get right, because there aren't really "rules" for how people can name their companies. It's easy to find examples of company names where converting to Title Case would be wrong, like "McDonald's", "IBM", etc. (Not that those are _your_ companies, but even if you don't have any like that right now, it seems easy enough that you could later.) If you convert them to all lowercase, all uppercase, there's no way to get back the original case.

Comment: This is for an internal returns management system. So yes, xReprisal, you do understand correctly. The users are NOT from the companies themselves they are workers who need to handle returned product in different stages. I think all uppercase would be the best of both worlds. It looks better than lowercase for the user and would be just as easy to convert and store.